# Blazor Server app hangs during HttpMessageHandler cleanup

Tags: blazor-server-side

We have a Blazor Server app that sometimes hangs for about 4 minutes after a deployment the first time someone logs into the app. The only reason I've been able to find in the logs is what looks like the HttpMessageHandler cleanup processing. I have the following logs that show what I'm referring to. I don't think the app is supposed to hang while the cleanup happens, but I can't find any other reason.

We are using in-house IIS servers (2 load balanced), a database server, and an Identity Server.

```
11:26:03.928 ServerName TRACE Authorization Filter: Before executing OnAuthorizationAsync on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.
11:26:03.930 ServerName TRACE Authorization Filter: After executing OnAuthorizationAsync on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.
11:26:03.930 ServerName TRACE Resource Filter: Before executing OnResourceExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.
11:26:03.931 ServerName TRACE Resource Filter: After executing OnResourceExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.
11:26:03.936 ServerName DEBUG Executing page model factory for page ServerProjectName.Pages.Pages__Host (ServerProjectName)
11:26:03.937 ServerName DEBUG Executed page model factory for page ServerProjectName.Pages.Pages__Host (ServerProjectName)
11:26:03.942 ServerName TRACE Page Filter: Before executing OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.PageHandlerPageFilter.
Looks like two minutes of nothing happening here
BEGIN: 4 Minute Gap
11:28:04.198 ServerName DEBUG HttpMessageHandler expired after 120000ms for client 'HttpClientName'
11:28:14.212 ServerName DEBUG Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
11:28:14.218 ServerName DEBUG Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.1051ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
11:28:24.232 ServerName DEBUG Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0081ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
11:28:24.232 ServerName DEBUG Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
11:28:34.248 ServerName DEBUG Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
11:28:34.248 ServerName DEBUG Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0077ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
11:28:44.264 ServerName DEBUG Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0206ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
11:28:44.264 ServerName DEBUG Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
11:28:54.279 ServerName DEBUG Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0067ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
11:28:54.279 ServerName DEBUG Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
11:29:04.295 ServerName DEBUG Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
11:29:04.300 ServerName DEBUG Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0073ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
11:29:14.295 ServerName DEBUG Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0071ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
11:29:14.295 ServerName DEBUG Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
11:29:24.310 ServerName DEBUG Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
11:29:24.311 ServerName DEBUG Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0068ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
11:29:34.311 ServerName DEBUG Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0064ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
11:29:34.311 ServerName DEBUG Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
11:29:44.326 ServerName DEBUG Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
11:29:44.326 ServerName DEBUG Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0074ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
11:29:54.342 ServerName DEBUG Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
11:29:54.342 ServerName DEBUG Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0072ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
11:30:04.357 ServerName DEBUG Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
11:30:04.361 ServerName DEBUG Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.006ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
11:30:14.373 ServerName DEBUG Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
11:30:14.373 ServerName DEBUG Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0069ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
11:30:24.373 ServerName DEBUG Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
11:30:24.373 ServerName DEBUG Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0064ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
11:30:34.389 ServerName DEBUG Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0071ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 1 items
11:30:34.389 ServerName DEBUG Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 1 items
END: 4 Minute Gap
11:30:34.411 ServerName INFORMATION Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://site/welcome - -
11:30:34.412 ServerName TRACE All hosts are allowed.
11:30:34.413 ServerName DEBUG Request matched endpoint '/_Host'
```

Comment: First question might seem dumb-- have you written a custom HttpMessageHandler?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Actually, a good question. Yes, there is a message handler for authorization token management by duende identity provider.

Comment: Well, hang on.  On second look, your handler is taking only like 0.1s once very 10 minutes.  That makes me think these are just regular clean-up notices and mean nothing.  What kind of server are you using?  Don't say GoDaddy shared hosting or something like that.  If so, then if you haven't used your free Azure credits, consider spinning up a VM and seeing if it has the same problem.

Comment: I'll update my question with some added info. We are using in-house IIS servers (2 load balanced), a database server, and an Identity Server. Recreating this in Azure will require quite a bit of work.

Comment: I wouldn't bother then.  The only time I've had a VERY slow startup like you describe is when I first run a project in an updated Visual Studio-- the debugger shows symbols loading one-by-one and that takes an extremely long time, like maybe a couple or several minutes.  But after that, even if I rebuild the whole project and run it again, I don't get that symbols loading message unless packages or VS have been updated.  Is supect you are compiling a debug version, right?

Comment: You continue to ask questions to make me realize I need to add more detail in my question. This is running in IIS on a staging server deployed in release configuration. There is no VS involved. My suspicion is that this must be related to something happening in IIS and maybe how the HttpClient is being setup in Program.cs. I'm really just guessing though.

Comment: Forgive me for brainstorming without real knowledge.  I'm curious if you are using framework-dependent or self-contained deployment.  4 mins is really an excessive delay to start anything, unless you are spinning up an entire VM or something-- and probably even then it shouldn't take that long.